# Unit testing modules in app/utils for an ember-cli app

Tags: javascript, ember.js, qunit, ecmascript-6, ember-cli

Calling `moduleFor` on `"util:transforms"` appears to work,
however `.subject` is `undefined`.

The test file that I have got so far is:

```
import { test, moduleFor } from 'ember-qunit';
import TransformUtil from 'myapp/utils/transforms';

moduleFor('util:transforms', "Unit - TransformUtil");

test("Exists", function(){
  expect(1);
  ok(this.subject() instanceof TransformUtil);
});
```

Doing the same thing for other type of modules,
e.g. `"routes:index"`, appears to work without issue;
the `app/utils` folder appears to be treated differently.

Answer (score -1):

Utilities (`app/utils`) are not identified by the resolver, so you need to do a manual import. As the Ember CLI documentation states:

> All modules in the app directory can be loaded by the resolver but typically classes such as mixins and utils should be loaded manually with an import statement.

So you should remove the first parameter to `moduleFor` and then just use the imported `TransformUtil` object in your tests.